# Mail server Dns configuration

Tags: dns, mail-server

this is my question:

I'm italian, i'have a local mail server and my new adsl company block 110 and 25 ports !!!

I routed blocked ports from a VPS to my server by a VPN trunk without problems, but i have some dns issue:

My local dns is myhome.no-ip.org and the vps' dns is www.myvps.eu The mail domain is myhome.no-ip.org (an email is jhon@myhome.no-ip.org )

In home's dns configuration i can only set the MX record (with old adsl company it was 'myhome.no-ip.org' and now i changed on 'www.myvps.eu')

In Vps' dns configuration I can modify any record (nothing changed now.... i don't know what to do !!)

Sending email to this mailserver i receive errors in A and AAAA records, but i can't undestand what to do:

Technical details of temporary failure:

DNS Error: 124237309

DNS type 'mx' lookup of myhome.no-ip.org responded with code NOERROR

124237309 DNS type 'aaaa' lookup of www.myvps.eu. responded with code NXDOMAIN

124237309 DNS type 'a' lookup of www.myvps.eu. responded with code NXDOMAIN

Before changing Adsl company all goes good, so the mail server is OK, it seems to be a DNS issue

Thanks to all!